# Manual jar extraction vs Tomcat unpack

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, deployment, jar, war

One of my work is deploying war files in the tomcat server and I'm doing this for years. The way I deploy is; stop tomcat, copy the war to the newly created directory which I set as an `appbase` in the tomcat virtual hosting and start the tomcat to extract the war under appbase, and finally stop tomcat, move extracted directory from appbase to webapps and start the tomcat finally. This procedure is strictly recommended by our developers as they were complaining because they used to get some mails if I directly place the war under webapps due to multiple auto deploys. This way it's fine for us and never faced any problem on the production server.

My question is,

Is the manual extraction with the command line `mkdir myapp;cd myapp;jar -xf /path/myapp.war` and the way the tomcat extracts same?. I want to write a script, Could there be any problem if I manually extract the war file with `jar` command and place it in the webapps and start the tomcat instead of letting tomcat unpack the war?. Does it work, is it recommended for production server or does it make any difference the way the tomcat extracts if it does any thing mysteriously which jar couldn't?.

Need help, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unless your configuration is broken somehow, replacing the WAR file (or exploded-WAR-directory) in the `webapps/` directory should cause the webapp to be redeployed -- and deployed only a single time. If you share more of your configuration, I might be able to comment on why you are experiencing double-deployment.

Comment: I am just a system admin and I'll just manage tomcat server but no idea of app inner functionality. The way it's been deployed is not a problem at all but thinking how about if I manually extract the war and if it make any difference with tomcat native unpack.

Comment: There is essentially no difference between unpacking the WAR yourself versus having Tomcat unpack it. If you want to leave Tomcat running, then it's actually better to let Tomcat unpack the WAR file because otherwise Tomcat might detect a change to your webapp (say, an updated JAR file or .class file) and reload *during* your manual unpacking operation, which may cause significant instability in your webapp. If Tomcat manages the unpacking, it won't make mistakes like that.

Comment: Ok tomcat's unpack is recommended. And, if I specify appbase as webapps and place the war directly in webapps, as each app has virtual hosting, it reloads the wars those many times the number of vhost specified. This is why I specified appbase as unique for each application and again moving them to webapps.

Comment: Virtual hosting is automatic: each <Host> defines a host and must have a name (the hostname to which is will respond). You must also have a default host for the <Engine> -- that one gets all requests that don't match any other <Host>. Each <Host> has an `appBase` where you can drop WAR files (or exploded-WAR directories). Each WAR (or dir) gets deployed as a separate webapp (aka context). If you specify the *same* appbase for every <Host>, you will get multiple (separate!) deployments of *all* the webapps. A unique `appbase` is recommended for each <Host> to reduce confusion.